# Not able to bind click event with button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Not sure, Where and what I am doing wrong. I have done this 100 of times in past and have never faced such issue.
I have following HTML button

```
<input class="button wide" type="button" id="hello123" onclick="test()" value="CLEAR FORM" style="alignment-adjust:"  />
```

and a simple test function

```
function test(){
   alert("test");
}
```

I am testing it on Chrome, but getting following exception under console

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined
```

I also tried to bind click event using Jquery with following code

```
$( "#hello123" ).bind( "click", function() {
    alert( "User clicked on 'button.'" );
});
```

Not sure what exact is the issue

Strange thins is, I have few other function in my JSP file and they are getting triggered perfectly fine.

I found what exact is issue

```
var validator = $("#register_form").validate({
  validator.resetForm();
  focusCleanup: true,
 // some rules etc

});
```

and `validator.resetForm();` is causing issue

Comment: Do you have your js files included ?

Comment: I created a [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/7bJcB/) and your first example works fine http://fiddle.jshell.net/7bJcB/ We will need to see the entire page to help you debug the problem.

Comment: looks like the `test` is defined in a local scope.. not in a global scope

Comment: Most likely you defined `test` inside $(function() {}) or similar. It's not in global scope.

Comment: Are you able to view the test() function in page source?

Comment: may be use miss <!DOCTYPE html> on IE??

Comment: @ArunPJohny: I have even changed function name..and this is not working :)

Comment: @AyyappanSekar: Yes I am able to see `test` in source code

Comment: try `window.test = function (){
   alert("test");
}`

Answer (score 0):

If we define the bind inside document ready then its working fine please refer the below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$( "#hello123" ).bind( "click", function() {alert( "User clicked on 'button.'" );
});

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/94u58/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
<title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input class="button wide" type="button" id="hello123" onclick="test()" value="CLEAR FORM" style="alignment-adjust:" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function test() {
    alert("test");
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#hello123").bind("click", function () {
        alert("User clicked on 'button.'");
    });
});

</script> 
</body>
</html>
```